# Sink overflow drain not cast all the way through

Tags: plumbing, sink, overflow

I have two sinks which are part of the countertop (single unit/casting). One sink is perfect. The other has never had a working overflow. I thought it was clogged but it appears that the overflow hole was not cast properly. I can see where it stops and it looks like the ceramic the sink is cast from.

Is this a problem that I can solve without replacing the sink?

My next step is to take the drain out and see if the overflow cast underneath the sink goes through to the vicinity of the overflow inlet or not.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, unless it's just lightly plugged with a thin flash (eggshell thickness or so) you can break through without breaking the overflow channel (either out to the underside or in to the sink bowl.) If it's a plug of thickness similar to the channel walls, I doubt you'll get through it without going wrong in one of those directions.

This should have been inspected and found at the time of original installation when it would more easily have been resolved by return to the supplier for a correct one. If you have a really top-notch supplier that *might* still be possible.

Comment: This sink has been in place since I bought the home 5 years ago and installed for some time before that. A warranty is out of the question. It would be worth my time to identify the maker and see if perhaps this is a known issue.

Comment: The blockage is non-trivial. I probed with a wire coathanger thinking it was a clog. I then grabbed a ceramic drill bit and using my hand got a little more aggressive. Definitely thicker than flashing!